# SQL SERVER stored procedure library database max loans check

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm designing a library database where users are restricted to a maximum number of loan items.

I'm trying to write a procedure that checks if they have reached their maximum limit.

The data is in two seperate tables:

---

**USERS**

- UsersID
- UsersMaxBooks (the number of books they are allowed to borrow)

---

**ITEMS**

- ItemsID
- FK_UsersID
- LoanDateOut (this will be populated with today's date when the book is borrowed)
- LoanDateReturned (this will be populated with today's date when the book is returned)

---

My procedure will say:

- COUNT the number of rows in Items
- WHERE FK_UsersID = @UsersID
- AND LoanDateOut is NOT NULL
- AND LoanDateReturned is NULL

(this will return the number of books that the user has taken out and NOT RETURNED)

- IF the number of rows returned is < Users.MaxBooks
- THEN add a new row to Items

  - ItemsID = @itemsID
  - FK_UsersID = @usersID
  - LoanDateOut = today's date
- ELSE loan not possible

Can anyone help me figure this out? I'm a newbie and am struggling to find a way to combine all these aspects in one procedure.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BorrowProcess (@user VARCHAR(255)) AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @userid INT = (
            SELECT usersid
            FROM users
            WHERE User = @user
            );
    DECLARE @max INT = (
            SELECT usermaxbooks
            FROM users where userid = @userid
            )
    DECLARE @booksout INT = (
            SELECT count(itemsid)
            FROM items
            WHERE dateout IS NOT NULL
                AND datein IS NULL
                AND fkuserid = @userid
            );

    IF @booksout >= @max
    BEGIN
        --— google raise error
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        ---— do INSERT
    END
END
GO
```

Here you go - type from the phone so clean it up yourself.

Comment: Also you need to add a user column to your user table that would have some kind of real world readable string